# Composer выдал ошибку при установке laravel проекта

Tags: php, laravel, git, cmd, composer

[image: Composer выдает ошибку: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Как исправить? Laravel проект установился но выдал такую ошибку]

Composer выдает ошибку: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Как исправить? Laravel проект установился но выдал такую ошибку

Comment: Вместо скриншота, вставьте вывод текстом - так ваш вопрос проидексируется и будет полезен еще кому-нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как следует из описания ошибки, у вас, в настройках PHP, не включен модуль `fileinfo`, который требуется для установки проекта. Как временный вариант, вам предлагается запустить composer c флагом `composer --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo ...`, чтобы проигнорировать это требование при установке.